Postfix SpamHouse Blocklist testing report not All fine 2/5
Postfix+Spamhouse test not all ok

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
    reject_rbl_client xbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rbl_client pbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rbl_client dbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_unverified_recipient,
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unauth_destination

VPS02 postfix/postfix-script[3113]: starting the Postfix mail system
VPS02 postfix/master[3115]: daemon started -- version 3.9.1, configuration /etc/postfix
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: warning: dict_nis_init: NIS domain name not set - NIS lookups disabled
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: connect from unlisted.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.101]
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: 174FB43713: client=unlisted.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.101]
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: disconnect from unlisted.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.101] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 quit=1 commands=4
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: connect from sbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.84]
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from sbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.84]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [199.168.89.84] blocked using zen.spamhaus.org; Error: open resolver; https://check.spamhaus.org/returnc/pub/2400:cb00:555:1024::ac47:b57a/; from=<test@sbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net> to=<my@mail.au> proto=ESMTP helo=<sbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net>
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: disconnect from sbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.84] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 quit=1 commands=3/4
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: connect from xbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.85]
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from xbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.85]: 554 5.7.1 Service unavailable; Client host [199.168.89.85] blocked using zen.spamhaus.org; Error: open resolver; https://check.spamhaus.org/returnc/pub/141.101.75.5/; from=<test@xbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net> to=<my@mail.au> proto=ESMTP helo=<xbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net>
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: disconnect from xbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.85] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 quit=1 commands=3/4
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: connect from pbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.86]
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: 08BCB43713: client=pbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.86]
VPS02 postfix/cleanup[3126]: 08BCB43713: message-id=<173458529339.536.4034820725571417784@blt.spamhaus.net>
VPS02 postfix/qmgr[3118]: 08BCB43713: from=<test@pbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net>, size=1456, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: disconnect from pbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.86] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
VPS02 postfix/relay/smtp[3127]: 08BCB43713: to=<my@mail.au>, relay=11.11.11.11[11.11.11.11]:35, delay=1.4, delays=0.57/0.02/0.28/0.48, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4YDJdW016mz1RmV)
VPS02 postfix/qmgr[3118]: 08BCB43713: removed
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: connect from unlisted.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.101]
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: 895EC43713: client=unlisted.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.101]
VPS02 postfix/cleanup[3126]: 895EC43713: message-id=<173458529509.536.1345710842566999611@blt.spamhaus.net>
VPS02 postfix/qmgr[3118]: 895EC43713: from=<test@unlisted.blt.spamhaus.net>, size=1468, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: disconnect from unlisted.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.101] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
VPS02 postfix/relay/smtp[3127]: 895EC43713: to=<my@mail.au>, relay=11.11.11.11[11.11.11.11]:35, delay=1.2, delays=0.41/0/0.54/0.25, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4YDJdX3Vv5z1RnB)
VPS02 postfix/qmgr[3118]: 895EC43713: removed
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: connect from dbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.87]
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: 5C61F43713: client=dbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.87]
VPS02 postfix/cleanup[3126]: 5C61F43713: message-id=<173458529675.536.1974504798552098920@blt.spamhaus.net>
VPS02 postfix/qmgr[3118]: 5C61F43713: from=<test@dbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net>, size=1470, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
VPS02 postfix/smtpd[3119]: disconnect from dbl-pub.blt.spamhaus.net[199.168.89.87] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
VPS02 postfix/relay/smtp[3127]: 5C61F43713: to=<my@mail.au>, relay=11.11.11.11[11.11.11.11]:35, delay=1, delays=0.56/0/0.24/0.24, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 4YDJdZ020Qz1RnB)
VPS02 postfix/qmgr[3118]: 5C61F43713: removed


Getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which is well written , on-topic and contains sufficient details to provide you with a good solution. Only a  statement  or an implied question without a ? is not enough.  - Please improve your question to address those points or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and/or having your question closed.

There's two answers to the question one of them is "Yes!" and other other is "Yes?"
